# How to pass a variable to split () in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, split, words

I'm new to the forum. Many Thanks to "stackoverflow" and you for the opportunity.

I have a problem. How I can pass a variable to a regular expression to split?

I have this:

```
var text = "I am new to the forum";
var term = "TO";

var textSplit = text.split(/term/gi);
```

What I like to do is to pass the variable "term" to the regular expression so you can divide if no match, but not how. Any idea better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

use the regex object and try this:

```
var modifiers = "gi"
var patt = new RegExp(term,modifiers);
var textSplit = text.split(patt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var term = /TO/gi;
var textSplit = text.split(term);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `term = "to"` is actually only a placeholder for some kind of user input.

Comment: Ah, good point. My bad.